# ftp_connect not returning resource, nor raising an error

Tags: php

I'm encountering a situation where ftp_connect() fails, returning a falsey value.  It doesn't raise an error (warning), therefore it doesn't enter the error handler.

php doesn't give me any error information so I don't know what to do next to resolve the issue (apart from looking at the c source for ftp_connect).

Does anybody know under what circumstances this is possible?

```
$this->connection = @ftp_connect($ip);
if (!$this->connection) {
    // Execution passes to here.
}
```

The call doesn't timeout, it returns the falsey value immmediately.  I say falsey because although it's probably returning FALSE, my code doesn't strictly check and it could be something else (i.e. NULL).

I cannot replicate the issue.  I know it's happening from log files, it continues to happen and it's seemingly arbitrary.

If I try and replicate the issue by changing $ip to be incorrect it will call the error handler.  From my tests the @ doesn't stop the error handler being called, it just (temporarily?) sets error_reporting to 0.

Comment: First: _stop_ using `@` preceding function calls. It explicitly _suppresses_ any notice or warning thrown. So don't complain that you don't get a notice or warning if you use it.

Comment: Second: What good does a statement like "my code doesn't strictly check and it could be something else" do when trying to find the cause of an issue? _Investigate that! Check that! It is_ your _code, not ours_.

Comment: Third: what is your actual question here? Your connection attempt fail. You suppress notifications in an explicit manner. And now you expect a _magical guess_ from our side pointing out what is going on?

Comment: Remove that `@` and start monitoring your http servers error log file. _Read_ the issue shown there. Most likely the ftp server refuses connections. There are millions of reasons why that may happen. Note that the ftp protocol is a left over from the 70th. It is totally outdated, insecure and should be avoided in most situations. There are better replacements.

Comment: There are a large number of possible reasons. You need to show what you've attempted and what details you've established *before* running to Stack Overflow for help. On other news, servers can turn off FTP connetions or they can use non-standard ports so have you checked these details with the server defined in `$ip`?

Comment: And as better stated by Arkarscha, stop using ftp it's completely insecure and should be replaced by other methods (SFTP, cURL, etc.) as quickly as practically possible.

Comment: cURL is not a network protocol, it's a library for network requests that supports many different protocols. Another option besides SFTP is SCP.

Comment: @tunny "it could be something else" - why don't you just check what $this->connection is?

Comment: @simon true, I was intending to simply name drop some alternatives to FTP for the OP to research and apply as needed.

Comment: I'll update the code to confirm if it's returning a false or not.

I'll also try and remove the @.  

The value in $ip is ok.  I tried not to overdo the detail in the initial question, but I'm looping and calling ftp_connect() multiple times.  I've seen it connect, fail, connect in the same second.

I'll look into how ftp_connect behaves when an ftp server refuses a connection, to see if this doesn't call the error handler.  I've asked the ftp server admin and they can't see any ftp issues.

I'm aware of ftp limitations, it's a 15 year old app, sftp is on the roadmap.